# Trouble with detecting color from HSV image using OpenCV and Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, colors, hsv

I am trying to perform a simple colored object detection using OpenCV and Python.

I have read several tutorials but I encounter a confusing problem that prevents me to progress. Although I provide correct data HSV, my program does not seem to detect objects of that color.

I use this image (sorry for the poor quality of my webcam):

[image: Sample]

In order to detect the red object, I recovered the HSV color data:

[image: Color data]

And here is my code:

```
YELLOW = 30
BLUE = 210
GREEN = 145
RED = 320

color = RED

img = cv2.imread("sample.png")

hue = color // 2

lower_range = np.array([max(0, hue - 10), 0, 0], dtype=np.uint8)
upper_range = np.array([min(180, hue + 10), 255, 255], dtype=np.uint8)

img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

mask = cv2.inRange(img, lower_range, upper_range)

binary_img = cv2.bitwise_and(img_hsv, img_hsv, mask=mask)
binary_img = cv2.cvtColor(binary_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, binary_img = cv2.threshold(binary_img, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

cv2.imshow('sample', binary_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Result:

[image: Result]

The result for others colors is correct (not perfect because of the poor quality I guess), but I can not get something for the red. Yet, the HSV converted image is quite explicit:

[image: HSV Image]

Do you see what am I doing wrong, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing everything right, the only problem is that you apply your threshold on the BGR image instead of the HSV.

Change:

```py
mask = cv2.inRange(img, lower_range, upper_range)
```

To

```py
mask = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, lower_range, upper_range)
```

I tested it and it looks just fine. I guess you'll need some morphological operations to get to your final result.

Comment: I am using HSV image but getting strange result. If you have some time, can you look at it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34170856/trying-to-detect-blue-color-from-image-using-opencv-and-getting-unexpected-resu)?